# LuaTex (?): Get access to the different layers of a glyph \char<No>

Tags: fonts, luatex, fontspec, directlua

[image] 
[ExampleFontWithLayers01.zip](https://github.com/cis555/fontspec/blob/develop/ExampleFontWithLayers01.zip) **(should be `\char0`)**

Sometimes a glyph is composed of different layers.
Random example: 
[image]

But a command of type `\char[layer=2]"1F0AE` is not available at the moment.

Is it possible with `LuaLaTeX` to get access to the contents of the different layers? 
Then outputs of the following type could be possible:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{<a font whose glyphs have several layers>}
 \char[<layer options>]"1F0AE
\end{document}
```

PS: I added `ExampleFontWithLayers.ttf`, where `\char0` contains the shown situation with layers. 
[ExampleFontWithLayers01.zip](https://github.com/cis555/fontspec/blob/develop/ExampleFontWithLayers01.zip)

Comment: I've looked with fontforge and `fonttools ttx` and I'm not seeing multiple layers for the glyph in the font you uploaded. But what your describing sounds like a COLRv0/CPAL font, which luaotfload does support.

Comment: Do you have openend the ttf-file with FontForge?

Comment: Yes, and I can only see a single layer. Even when disassembling the `.ttf` with `fonttools`, I'm only seeing a boring `GLYF` table.

Comment: Should be fixed now.

Comment: The [layers are saved in a custom FontForge-exclusive `PfEd`/`layr` table](https://fontforge.org/docs/techref/non-standard.html#layr-background-layer-data). I'm sure that it's possible to parse this from Lua, but you'd be much better off converting this to or acquiring a `COLR`v0/`CPAL` version.

Comment: The example ttf-file shows one glyph with different layers. Imagine this with a font file containing thousands of characters (e.g. Japanese characters). I would therefore have a solution that can be used in the document.

Comment: I agree that this is useful, but the layers in that format are a weird FontForge-specific thing that no other editor, and no renderers at all support. Because of that, I doubt that there are many (if any at all) fonts like that. This feature is supported with the COLRv0 format, which most OTF/TTF renderers (including LuaTeX/`luaotfload`) already support.

Comment: Aha, I didn't know that glyph-layers are a specific FontForge-thing.